# Google Maps API - Find Nearest Locations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a spreadsheet of around 250 office locations across the US. I want to have a web page where a user would enter their home address and the five nearest offices (name, city, phone number, etc.) would be listed on the left and the points mapped on the map canvas. Do you know how I can implement this scenario using Google Maps API?

I have figured out how to get the data loaded into the map using GeoJSON, but I have not been able to learn how I can present the five nearest sites based upon driving distance or time. I did find the Distance Matrix Service, but it is limited to 25 destinations per request, so that won’t work.

The haversine method that others have suggested will not work in this scenario, as I need the calculations to be based upon either driving distance, or more usefully, driving time. Also, I do not have access to PHP in this case, but we can use JavaScript.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the haversine method to reduce the number of points to a number that can be run through the distance matrix, then use the distance matrix to generate the final 5 points.

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_closestPlaces10sort.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];

function initialize() {
  // alert("init");
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6699927, -0.7274620),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "found " + locations.length + " locations<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var coordStr = locations[i][4];
    var coords = coordStr.split(",");
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    bounds.extend(pt);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pt,
      map: map,
      icon: locations[i][5],
      address: locations[i][2],
      title: locations[i][0],
      html: locations[i][0] + "<br>" + locations[i][2]
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })
      (marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}

function codeAddress() {
  var numberOfResults = 25;
  var numberOfDrivingResults = 5;
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
      customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location, numberOfResults);
      // get driving distance
      closest = closest.splice(0, numberOfResults);
      calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest, numberOfDrivingResults);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function findClosestN(pt, numberOfResults) {
  var closest = [];
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing " + gmarkers.length + "<br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt, gmarkers[i].getPosition());
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process " + i + ":" + gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + ":" + gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
  }
  closest.sort(sortByDist);
  return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a, b) {
  return (a.distance - b.distance)
}

function calculateDistances(pt, closest, numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request = {
    origins: [pt],
    destinations: [],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
    request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title and address in record for sorting
      for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
        results[i].title = closest[i].title;
        results[i].address = closest[i].address;
        results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      results.sort(sortByDistDM);
      for (var i = 0;
        ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' appoximately ' + results[i].duration.text + '<br><hr>';
      }
    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
// Store Name[0],delivery[1],Address[2],Delivery Zone[3],Coordinates[4] data from FusionTables pizza stores example
var locations = [
  ["John's Pizza", "no", "400 University Ave, Palo Alto, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.121277,37.386799,0 -122.158012,37.4168,0 -122.158012,37.448151,0 -122.142906,37.456055,0 -122.118874,37.45224,0 -122.107544,37.437793,0 -122.102737,37.422526,0 -122.113037,37.414618,0 -122.121277,37.386799,0   </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.447038,-122.160575", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "1000 Santa Cruz Ave, Menlo Park, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.200928,37.438611,0 -122.158012,37.4168,0 -122.158012,37.448151,0 -122.142906,37.456055,0 -122.144623,37.475948,0 -122.164192,37.481125,0 -122.189255,37.478673,0 -122.208481,37.468319,0 -122.201271,37.438338,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.448638,-122.187176", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John Paul's Pizzeria", "no", "1100 El Camino Real, Belmont, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.304268,37.516534,0 -122.300835,37.505096,0 -122.262383,37.481669,0 -122.242813,37.502917,0 -122.244186,37.534232,0 -122.269249,37.550021,0 -122.291222,37.545122,0 -122.302895,37.537499,0 -122.304268,37.516534,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.520436,-122.275978", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "300 E 4th Ave, San Mateo, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.304268,37.516534,0 -122.348557,37.538044,0 -122.359886,37.56363,0 -122.364006,37.582405,0 -122.33654,37.589207,0 -122.281609,37.570433,0 -122.291222,37.545122,0 -122.302895,37.537499,0 -122.304268,37.516534,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.564435,-122.322080", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "yes", "1400 Broadway Ave, Burlingame, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.374306,37.548933,0 -122.348557,37.538044,0 -122.359886,37.56363,0 -122.364006,37.582405,0 -122.33654,37.589207,0 -122.359543,37.59764,0 -122.372246,37.604712,0 -122.417564,37.594648,0 -122.374306,37.548933,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.584935,-122.366182", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "700 San Bruno Ave, San Bruno, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.462883,37.628916,0 -122.445374,37.639247,0 -122.426147,37.648762,0 -122.405205,37.642238,0 -122.400055,37.628644,0 -122.392159,37.610696,0 -122.372246,37.604712,0 -122.417564,37.594648,0 -122.462196,37.628644,0  </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.630934,-122.406883", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "300 Beach St, San Francisco, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.43576,37.790795,0 -122.449493,37.801646,0 -122.425461,37.809784,0 -122.402115,37.811411,0 -122.390442,37.794593,0 -122.408295,37.79188,0 -122.434387,37.789167,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.807628,-122.413782", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "1400 Haight St, San Francisco, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.463398,37.760266,0 -122.477349,37.774785,0 -122.427349,37.774785,0 -122.429237,37.763658,0 -122.46357,37.760808,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.770129,-122.445082", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "2400 Mission St, San Francisco, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.418766,37.747779,0 -122.425289,37.768951,0 -122.406063,37.769901,0 -122.406063,37.749679,0 -122.418251,37.747508,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.758630,-122.419082", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "500 Castro St, Mountain View, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.121277,37.386799,0 -122.108917,37.362244,0 -122.077675,37.3385,0 -122.064285,37.378615,0 -122.069778,37.3898,0 -122.076645,37.402619,0 -122.078705,37.411619,0 -122.113037,37.414618,0 -122.121277,37.386799,0  </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.390040,-122.081573", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "no", "100 S Murphy Ave, Sunnyvale, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.047119,37.33113,0 -122.065315,37.332495,0 -122.077675,37.3385,0 -122.064285,37.378615,0 -122.036819,37.385162,0 -122.006607,37.382162,0 -122.00386,37.342048,0 -122.047119,37.331403,0  </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.377441,-122.030071", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "no", "1200 Curtner Ave, San Jose, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-121.935196,37.345051,0 -121.931076,37.294267,0 -121.871338,37.293721,0 -121.806793,37.293174,0 -121.798553,37.361426,0 -121.879578,37.36088,0 -121.934509,37.345597,0 -121.935196,37.345051,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.288742,-121.890765", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "yes", "700 Blossom Hill Rd, San Jose, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-121.935883,37.253287,0 -121.931076,37.294267,0 -121.871338,37.293721,0 -121.806793,37.293174,0 -121.790657,37.234702,0 -121.852455,37.223221,0 -121.935539,37.253014,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.250543,-121.846563", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "yes", "100 N Milpitas Blvd, Milpitas, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-121.947556,37.435612,0 -121.934509,37.476493,0 -121.893311,37.469409,0 -121.852798,37.429615,0 -121.843872,37.400165,0 -121.887817,37.3898,0 -121.959915,37.420345,0 -121.959915,37.427979,0 -121.948929,37.435612,0 -121.947556,37.435612,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.434113,-121.901139", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "yes", "3300 Mowry Blvd, Fremont, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.02343,37.52198,0 -122.023773,37.558731,0 -121.989784,37.573426,0 -121.959572,37.566351,0 -121.944466,37.544305,0 -121.967125,37.520891,0 -122.023087,37.522525,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.552773,-121.985153", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  //New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.00594130000002)  
  ["New York, NY, USA", "no", "New York City Hall, New York, NY 10007, USA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.02343,37.52198,0 -122.023773,37.558731,0 -121.989784,37.573426,0 -121.959572,37.566351,0 -121.944466,37.544305,0 -121.967125,37.520891,0 -122.023087,37.522525,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "40.7127837, -74.0059413", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],
  // Newark, NJ, USA (40.735657, -74.1723667)  
  ["Newark, NJ, USA", "no", "169 Market St, Newark, NJ 07102, USA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.02343,37.52198,0 -122.023773,37.558731,0 -121.989784,37.573426,0 -121.959572,37.566351,0 -121.944466,37.544305,0 -121.967125,37.520891,0 -122.023087,37.522525,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "40.735657, -74.1723667", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],
  // Baltimore, MD, USA (39.2903848, -76.6121893
  ["Baltimore, MD, USA", "no", "201-211 E Fayette St, Baltimore, MD 21202, USA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.02343,37.52198,0 -122.023773,37.558731,0 -121.989784,37.573426,0 -121.959572,37.566351,0 -121.944466,37.544305,0 -121.967125,37.520891,0 -122.023087,37.522525,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "39.2903848, -76.6121893", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],
  // Boston, MA, USA (42.3600825, -71.05888
  ["Boston, MA, USA", "no", "City Hall Plaza, Boston, MA 02203, USA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.02343,37.52198,0 -122.023773,37.558731,0 -121.989784,37.573426,0 -121.959572,37.566351,0 -121.944466,37.544305,0 -121.967125,37.520891,0 -122.023087,37.522525,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "42.3600825, -71.05888", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],
  // Philadelphia, PA, USA (39.9525839, -75.16522150000003)
  ["Philadelphia, PA, USA", "no", "1414 PA-611, Philadelphia, PA 19102, USA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.02343,37.52198,0 -122.023773,37.558731,0 -121.989784,37.573426,0 -121.959572,37.566351,0 -121.944466,37.544305,0 -121.967125,37.520891,0 -122.023087,37.522525,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "39.9525839, -75.1652215", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"]
];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map" style="height: 600px; width:500px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="side_bar"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="address" type="text" value="Palo Alto, CA"></input>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress();"></input>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

/**

- Use This Function to send batch of 25 destination at a time to Google Distance Matrix Function , get the results back in X number of array and Finally merege them all . see the comments for more details .
  .
- Use Distance Matrix API to calculate distance from origin to each store.
- @param {google.maps.Data} data The geospatial data object layer for the map
- @param {google.maps.LatLng} origin Geographical coordinates in latitude
- and longitude
- @return {Promise<object[]>} n Promise fulfilled by an array of objects with
- a distanceText, distanceVal, and storeid property, sorted ascending
- by distanceVal.
  */

```
async function calculateDistances(data, origin) {

    const destinations = [];
    const stores = [];
    const destinations_p = [];

    // Build parallel arrays for the store IDs and destinations
    data.forEach((store) => {

        const storeNum = store.getProperty('storeid');
        const storeLoc = store.getGeometry().get();

        destinations_p.push(storeLoc);
        stores.push(storeNum);


    });

    destinations.push(destinations_p, stores);
    //console.log(destinations);
    /******************************************************************************************
    I thought this step above would be helpful to make 2 dimentional array and send it to 
    distance metrix service and get storeid sorted in that function but distance matrix only 
    allow a set of inputs to be taken in consideration , we cannot set additional custom identtifier
*******************************************************************************************/



    // Retrieve the distances of each store from the origin
    // The returned list will be in the same order as the destinations list
    const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    // console.log(service);
    const getDistanceMatrix =
        (service, parameters) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            service.getDistanceMatrix(parameters, (response, status) => {
                if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    reject(response);
                } else {
                    const distances = [];
                    const results = response.rows[0].elements;
                    //console.log(response);
                    for (let j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                        const element = results[j];
                        //console.log(element);
                        const distanceText = (element.status != 'ZERO_RESULTS') ? element.distance.text : '9999999999 km';
                        const distanceVal = (element.status != 'ZERO_RESULTS') ? element.distance.value : '9999999999 km';
                        const distanceObject = {
                            storeid: stores[j],
                            distanceText: distanceText,
                            distanceVal: distanceVal,
                        };
                        distances.push(distanceObject);
                    }

                    resolve(distances);
                }
            });
        });


    /***********************************************************************************
    This method was build to pass only 25 destinations in array to distance matrix 
    service , that's the max it was take at a time , if there is change to this 
    settings in google then only chnage max_records value below and it should work
    ************************************************************************************/
    let p_results = [];
    let p_process = [];
    let nextSet = [];
    var lastIndex = 0
    var max_records = 25;
    var p_stores = [];
    var flatArray = [];
    var total_records = Math.ceil(destinations[0].length / max_records);


    // later i figured out that foreach does not work with async function however FOR loop works

    /*  data.forEach((store) => {
      let p_val = store.getGeometry().get().lat()+","+store.getGeometry().get().lng();
      p_results.push("["+p_val+"]");
        });
    */


    for (var g = 1; g <= total_records; g++) {

        let nextSet = [];

        /*************************************************************
        These debugging could be use to match what we are sending 
        matching with destination and storeid'd in parallel array
        console.log(destinations[0].slice(lastIndex, max_records));
        console.log(destinations[1].slice(lastIndex, max_records));
        *************************************************************/
        nextSet.push(destinations[0].slice(lastIndex, max_records));

        lastIndex = max_records;
        max_records = lastIndex + 25;

        /*********************************************************************************************
        There is some issue going on with hawaii lats and lng - This is Test for that these are hawaii
        lat,lng , I have opened Ticket with google : https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/189164319
           
           p_process.push(await getDistanceMatrix(service, {
              origins: ['21.304247103770592,-157.8504303328067'],
              destinations: ['19.638878300603324,-155.9901696156307','19.666046167473695,-155.99401485525755','19.517828633585925,-155.92144357145344','19.927879613527526,-155.78726601617393','21.304247103770592,-157.8504303328067'],
              travelMode: 'DRIVING',
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            }));
        
        *********************************************************************************************/

        p_process.push(await getDistanceMatrix(service, {
            origins: [origin],
            destinations: nextSet[0],
            travelMode: 'DRIVING',
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        }));


    }; // end for loop


    /**********************************************************
    So i get back array results from getDistance matrix and now
    they are nice stacked in 3,4,5 etc # of array depends on how
    many set of 25's where passed , now to process further more
    we need to merge all these array togather and stamp back 
    storeID - if you get 'undefined' error that means somehow 
    there is mismatch between array and loop count .
    **********************************************************/



    flatArray = Array.prototype.concat(...p_process);
    for (var h = 0; h < flatArray.length; h++) {

        flatArray[h].storeid = h; // reassigning storeid

    };


    // finally sorting array's
    flatArray.sort((first, second) => {
        return first.distanceVal - second.distanceVal;
    });


    return flatArray;

}; // end function
```